# Error on installing Netbeans 12.0 using the official installer

Tags: linux, netbeans, debian, netbeans-11

### Problem description:

I am trying to install Netbeans 12.0 on Debian "Buster", using the official Netbeans installer. Though the following exception occures:

```
No protocol specified
Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

Maybe you know a solution for the above problem?

Thank you for your time!

***Note:*** I know that I could install Netbeans 12.0 as a snap package, but here I'm not interested in it.

---

### Followed steps:

**1)** In Terminal, I logged-in as the *root* user:

```
$ su

Password: ***
```

**2)** I installed the package [openjdk-11-jdk](https://packages.debian.org/en/buster/openjdk-11-jdk):

```
$ apt install default-jdk
```

**3)** Then I checked the *java* version:

```
$ java --version

openjdk 11.0.7 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.7+10-post-Debian-3deb10u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.7+10-post-Debian-3deb10u1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

**4)** I downloaded the three files specified by the official documentation ([Downloading Apache NetBeans 12.0](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb120/nb120.html)) into *"~/Downloads"* folder:

- The installer file (*"Apache-NetBeans-12.0-bin-linux-x64.sh"*) from the offered [mirror site](https://downloads.apache.org/netbeans/netbeans/12.0/Apache-NetBeans-12.0-bin-linux-x64.sh);
- The [PGP ASC](https://downloads.apache.org/netbeans/netbeans/12.0/Apache-NetBeans-12.0-bin-linux-x64.sh.asc) file (*"Apache-NetBeans-12.0-bin-linux-x64.sh.asc"*);
- The [KEYS](https://downloads.apache.org/netbeans/KEYS) file.

**5)** I navigated to the *"Downloads"* folder:

```
$ cd Downloads
```

**6)** I set the *execute* permission on the Netbeans installer file:

```
$ chmod +x Apache-NetBeans-12.0-bin-linux-x64.sh
```

**7)** Because the Netbeans documentation specifies this:

> Officially, it is important that you [verify the integrity](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi#verify) of the
> downloaded files using the PGP signatures (.asc file) [...]. The PGP
> signatures should be matched against the [KEYS](https://downloads.apache.org/netbeans/KEYS) file which contains
> the PGP keys used to sign this release.

I followed the two steps (the ones using *gpg*) that they are providing in their [link](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi#verify), in order to verify the integrity of the installer:

**7.a)** Importing *KEYS* file:

```
$ gpg --import KEYS

gpg: Schlüssel B4C1940FEA9364F1: "Jan Lahoda (Key for signing Apache NetBeans & co. releases.) <jlahoda@apache.org>" nicht geändert
gpg: Schlüssel 13E9F7AE3A4FD551: "geertjan@apache.org (Key for signing Apache NetBeans & co. releases.) <geertjan@apache.org>" nicht geändert
gpg: Schlüssel CF7BA0AB1CCF4647: "Emilian Marius Bold <emi@apache.org>" nicht geändert
gpg: Schlüssel B2BF814FA145CB2D: "Laszlo Kishalmi (CODE SIGNING KEY) <lkishalmi@apache.org>" nicht geändert
gpg: Schlüssel 4A2601CEDA9382F3: "Eric Barboni (Signing Key) <skygo@apache.org>" nicht geändert
gpg: Schlüssel 3703AC389A12A9D4: "Neil C Smith <neilcsmith@apache.org>" nicht geändert
gpg: Schlüssel 57D5896CD86C1320: "Reema Taneja (Code Signing Key) <rtaneja@apache.org>" nicht geändert
gpg: Schlüssel E860B148D27236F9: "Jaroslav Tulach (Key for signing Apache NetBeans & co. releases.) <jtulach@apache.org>" nicht geändert
gpg: Schlüssel 6FA863B0C32A18B1: Öffentlicher Schlüssel "Arunava Sinha (CODE SIGNING KEY) <arusinha@apache.org>" importiert
gpg: Schlüssel 3ED477750C09D18D: Öffentlicher Schlüssel "John McDonnell (CODE SIGNING KEY) <johnmcdonnell@apache.org>" importiert
gpg: Anzahl insgesamt bearbeiteter Schlüssel: 10
gpg:                              importiert: 2
gpg:                             unverändert: 8
```

**7.b)** Verifying the signature:

```
$ gpg --verify Apache-NetBeans-12.0-bin-linux-x64.sh.asc

gpg: die unterzeichneten Daten sind wohl in 'Apache-NetBeans-12.0-bin-linux-x64.sh'
gpg: Signatur vom Di 09 Jun 2020 17:50:58 CEST
gpg:                mittels RSA-Schlüssel 8FE1C26F15E0320E740BAED84A2601CEDA9382F3
gpg:                Aussteller "skygo@apache.org"
gpg: Korrekte Signatur von "Eric Barboni (Signing Key) <skygo@apache.org>" [unbekannt]
gpg: WARNUNG: Dieser Schlüssel trägt keine vertrauenswürdige Signatur!
gpg:          Es gibt keinen Hinweis, daß die Signatur wirklich dem vorgeblichen Besitzer gehört.
Haupt-Fingerabdruck  = 8FE1 C26F 15E0 320E 740B  AED8 4A26 01CE DA93 82F3
```

**8)** In the end, I executed the installer:

```
$ sh Apache-NetBeans-12.0-bin-linux-x64.sh

Configuring the installer...
Searching for JVM on the system...
Extracting installation data...
Running the installer wizard...
No protocol specified

Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

I also tried with *"bash"* command:

```
$ bash Apache-NetBeans-12.0-bin-linux-x64.sh
```

and with *"./"*:

```
$ ./Apache-NetBeans-12.0-bin-linux-x64.sh
```

Unfortunately, the result is the same each time:

```
No protocol specified
Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

---

### Update:

@Kryštof Vosyka gave the working solution: to install Netbeans 12.0 as the current user, **not** as the *root* user.

In order to apply his solution, all the above installation steps are to be followed, with the exception of step **6** (setting the *execute* permission on the Netbeans installer file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, and solution is quite simple:

**Don't start the installation as root.**

The installer is graphical and root user cannot really open windows for your user, thus failing.
No idea how to install it for all users, though.